# Undefined method by link_to helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I need to post through a link tag, however there is a problem with the link helper. Here is my link tag

```
// doctors.html.erb
<%= link_to "Ekle", [:add_doctor, @patient], method: :post %>
```

And my routes.rb

```
// routes.rb 
get    'patients/:id/doctors' => 'patients#get_doctors'
post   'patients/:id/doctors' => 'patients#add_doctor'
```

I get the error

**undefined method `add_doctor_patient_path' for #<#:0x007fd39283a4b0>**

How should I use link helper to get rid of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an as: option on the routes.

```
// routes.rb 
get    'patients/:id/doctors' => 'patients#get_doctors',as: :patient_get_doctor
post   'patients/:id/doctors' => 'patients#add_doctor', as: :patient_add_doctor
```

Then in the view:

```
// doctors.html.erb
<%= link_to "Ekle", patient_add_doctor_path(id: @patient.id), method: :post %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line in your `routes.rb` shows that you have a `get_doctors` route that accepts one argument, `:id`:

```
get 'patients/:id/doctors' => 'patients#get_doctors'
```

That means you should use the corresponding path helper, `get_doctors_path`, and pass it the Patient object:

```
<%= link_to "Ekle", get_doctors_path(@patient), method: :post %>
```

P.S. Your routes are puzzling, since you could accomplish the same thing by using resourceful routes, [as recommended by the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), instead of defining your own custom `get` and `post` routes, and in so doing save yourself a lot of trouble:

```
resources :patients do
  resources :doctors
end
```

This would create e.g. `patient_doctors_path` and `new_patient_doctor_path` path helpers that would automatically route to your `DoctorsController#get` and `DoctorsController#new` methods, respectively, and it would enable you to use e.g. `form_for [ @patient, :doctor ]`. PatientsController is very much the wrong place to put logic for retrieving and modifying Doctors.